# How to tweak a Sublime Text 2 theme?

Tags: themes, sublimetext2

I love the Sublime Text's Monokai theme. Except for one thing: it is difficult to distinguish the active tab from inactive.  So I want to make the inactive tab a bit lighter.

I've looked through Monokai.tmTheme file and don't really know what to change (or even if it's the right file).

So, how do I change the background color of the Inactive Tab?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  Go to `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Default\Default.sublime-theme`

Go to line 529 and mess with the last number in the `tint_modifier` key, until your find the color pleasing.